# django timezone dst change should not be observed for Asia/Tehran after 2023

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone, dst

Since 2023 Tehran observes standard Time all year and DST is no longer in use. Python datetime still uses DST for this zone.

for example:

`timezone.localtime(timezone.now())`
returns `datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 27, 17, 34, 6, 13634, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Tehran' +0430+4:30:00 DST>)`

but it should not consider DST and it should observer standard +3:30 time.

does anyone know how to change the DST consideration for Django a specific zone?

I have tried to use UTC timezone for my project and manually considering the +3:30 offset but I would like to user `Asia/Tehran` zone.

**Solved**

I user Python 3.9 but pytz version was old. I simply used `pip install --upgrade pytz` to update the pytz and problem was solved.

Comment: I suspect this is due to an outdated dependency in django: Both the newest version of pytz (2023.2) and Python 3.9+ zoneinfo (effectively using my system's zoneinfo on Linux) show 'Asia/Tehran' to be observing UTC+3:30, not +4:30.