# Django and Time Zone for regions that no longer observe the Daylight Save Time (DST)

Tags: python, django, timezone, dst

I have a Django project, time zone is enabled for multiple purposes, my `TIME_ZONE = 'America/Mexico_City'`, however, since this year 2023, in this time zone it's no longer observed the DST, I use the `localtime` to get the right date/time in some cases, but it detects the DST

```
>>> localtime(timezone.now())
datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 3, 10, 14, 49, 782365, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/Mexico_City' CDT-1 day, 19:00:00 DST>)
>>> timezone.now()
datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 3, 15, 14, 54, 953013, tzinfo=<UTC>)
>>> datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 3, 9, 15, 7, 628038)
```

`datetime.now()` has the correct date/time, of course I can change the `localtime` for `datetime.now()`, but there are a lot of them, I want to understand how I can "update" or "sync" my Django project so it take the correct DST when some region change it for both observe or not longer observe it.

Comment: related? https://stackoverflow.com/q/75856163/10197418

Comment: That's it! maybe that post wasn't appear by using my words, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: Solved

Thanks to @FObersteiner for the reference, my pytz version was old. Simply upgrade it with `pip install --upgrade pytz`, that will solve the issue.